# Comparing two private variables stored by custom objects that implements 'Comparable'

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I'm trying to take a paragraph and find its 'meaning' by printing out the top Three words. after strip out all the grammar word and white space, I use a Hashmap to count the occurrences of each word. then since I don't know of a better way, I just created my own little custom object to store the word, Key, and occurrence, value, just like the Hashmap, but my teacher suggested implementing Comparable, but I've run into a problem. I get two problems, one shows up when I 'fix' the other. The problem lies in the compareTo function in the Pair class, and the Sort() function in the other class. im getting a 'pair cannot be converted to boolean' when I have the compareTo function returning int. and it not letting me use the compareTo function.

compareTo() also I know that the compareTo should return int to Override, but this is how the code was when I jumped on here to ask for help. also the Class prototype is

```
    public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
    ///.... variables, getters, setters, etc.

    @Override
    public boolean compareTo(Pair o) {    // ERROR HERE

    boolean z = false;

    if (this.getValue() > o.getValue()) {
        z = true;
    }
    else{
        z = false;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

and the sort/countwords function that is using the Pair object.

```
public Pair[] sort(Pair[] arr) {
    int max;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Assume first element is min
        max = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j],compareTo(arr[max])  == true){ //ERROR HERE
                max = j;
            }
        }
        if (max != i) {
            final Pair temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[max];
            arr[max] = temp;
        }
        System.out.println(arr[i].getKey());// I print the in ascending order
    }
    return arr; 
}

public void countWords() {
    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap(); // set up a Hashmap to get the occurance of the words
    for (String a : dataList) {
        Integer freq = m.get(a);
        m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
    }
    //create and fill array of custom Pair (key, value) objects, so it becomes sortable
    int count = 0;
    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[m.size()];
    for (String key : m.keySet()) {
        Pair pair = new Pair(key, m.get(key));
        pairs[count] = pair;
        count++;
    }
    Pair[] sortedPairs = sort(pairs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compareTo()` has to return an int which respects the following:

return -1 if the current objects value is less than the other, 0 if they are equal and 1 if it's greater.

Change your method to (assuming getValue() returns an `int`):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Pair o) {
       return (this.getValue() < o.getValue()) ? -1 : (this.getValue() > o.getValue()) ? 1 : 0 ;
    }
```

Note that if `getValue()` returns other object type you could use that object's default implementation of `compareTo()`. So if `getValue()` would return for example a `BigDecimal` or `Integer` object, etc, you could just use `return this.getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());`

Then, when using the method, change the line

```
if (arr[j],compareTo(arr[max])  == true)
```

to

```
if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[max])  == 0 ) //they are equal
```

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()` has to return an `int`. It returns either -1 (object1 < object2), 0 (object1 == object2) or 1 (object1 > object2). In your code you would use it for example like this:

```
if ( pairA.compareTo(pairB) > 0 ) // if pairA > pairB
```

Answer (score 0):

compareTo must return an int, otherwise you are not actually implementing the abstract method defined in the interface.

Depending upon what type is being returned by the getValue() method in the Pair class you can most likely define the method simply as:

```
public int compareTo(Pair o) {    

   return getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());
}
```